# Confusion over theoretical vs actual performance for in-place vec modification

Tags: rust, vector, benchmarking

For the needs of a high-performance math library, I've been benchmarking various methods to do in-place operations on Rust vecs (and preferably by reference). These methods are:

- Using an explicit for loop
- Using an iterator then using a `map()`, collecting to a new vec, and overwriting the existing one
- Using an iterator then using `for_each()`

This is the benchmarking code:

```rust
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};

const N_ITEMS: usize = 100000;
const N_BENCH_TIMES: i32 = 100;

fn bench_simple() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = vec![5; N_ITEMS];
    for i in a.iter_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
}

fn bench_iterator() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = vec![5; N_ITEMS];
    let a: Vec<i32> = a.iter_mut().map(|x| *x + 1).collect();
}

fn bench_foreach() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = vec![5; N_ITEMS];
    a.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 1);
}

fn benchmark(name: &str, f: &dyn Fn()) {
    println!("Benchmark: {}", name);
    let mut time = Duration::new(0, 0);
    for _ in 0..N_BENCH_TIMES {
        let start_time = Instant::now();
        f();
        time += start_time.elapsed();
    }
    println!("Total: {:?} over {} instances", time, N_BENCH_TIMES);
    println!("Average: {:?}", time.div_f64(N_BENCH_TIMES as f64));
}

fn main() {
    benchmark("Simple", &bench_simple);
    benchmark("Iterator", &bench_iterator);
    benchmark("ForEach", &bench_foreach);
}
```

And these are the results:

```
Benchmark: Simple
Total: 402.619146ms over 100 instances
Average: 4.026191ms
Benchmark: Iterator
Total: 587.769728ms over 100 instances
Average: 5.877697ms
Benchmark: ForEach
Total: 409.527297ms over 100 instances
Average: 4.095273ms
```

The Rust docs say that:

> "In some cases `for_each` may also be faster than a loop, because it will use internal iteration on adapters like `Chain`"

so I expected `for_each()` to be faster than the for loop, and both to be much, much faster than the `map()`, which requires creating a new vector and using it to overwrite the existing one. But in benchmarks this is apparently not the case? Is my understanding of how the respective iterators work incorrect?

Comment: What CPU and compiler version?  What build options?  Release not debug, I hope.  Also, I notice that each invocation also creates a new vector.  Hopefully that takes about the same time each time...  But nothing uses the result, I'd hope that all the work would get optimized away.  Maybe it does in some but not all cases?  Or you're making a debug build, which is meaningless to benchmark. ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)).

Comment: 4 ms for `100000` elements is 0.025 elements per nanosecond.  That's absolute garbage.  You should be getting like 16 elements per nanosecond with basic SIMD vectorization doing one 16-byte vector (of 4x i32) per clock cycle, and a 4 GHz CPU running 4 cycles per nanosecond.  Either a debug build, or [what kind of chip you got in there, a Dorito?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpMvS1Q1sos).  Or if it has to actually init the array first, maybe half that.  (For a high-performance math library, you should be looking at `-C target-cpu=native` to enable AVX2+FMA on x86-64 for example.)

Comment: Ah, I see, the likely issue is most likely a combination of both a debug build and a very low-end chip. This is my first time doing performance evaluation so I was not aware that it would cause issues - probably should've read about it more!

Comment: Consider also using a proper benchmarking crate like [criterion](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/). In particular, make use of [`black_box`](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/fn.black_box.html) at appropriate points to prevent the optimizer from optimizing away what the benchmarks are actually meant to test.

Comment: `100000` x 4-byte elements is 390 KiB of data.  On some modern CPUs, that will fit in L2 cache.  If not, an optimized (auto-vectorized) loop will bottleneck on L3 cache bandwidth.  (I'd hope that all three ways optimize away any overhead and just end up looping over the data.)

Comment: For benchmarking, please always use a proper framework like [`criterion`](https://docs.rs/criterion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm quite confident that you are not building with `cargo run --release`, making your entire benchmark completely pointless.

Here is the output of your benchmark on a pretty old laptop of mine, **without** `--release`:

```
Benchmark: Simple
Total: 545.9198ms over 100 instances
Average: 5.459198ms
Benchmark: Iterator
Total: 461.5787ms over 100 instances
Average: 4.615787ms
Benchmark: ForEach
Total: 334.7625ms over 100 instances
Average: 3.347625ms
```

And here it is **with** `--release`:

```
Benchmark: Simple
Total: 10.6028ms over 100 instances
Average: 106.028µs
Benchmark: Iterator
Total: 176.4µs over 100 instances
Average: 1.764µs
Benchmark: ForEach
Total: 5.8382ms over 100 instances
Average: 58.382µs
```

So what's going on here?

The [resulting assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/MWG1sGqhn) sheds some light on it:

```
example::bench_iterator:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + __rust_no_alloc_shim_is_unstable@GOTPCREL]
        movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rax]
        mov     ecx, 99968
        test    rcx, rcx
        je      .LBB1_3
.LBB1_2:
        add     rcx, -32
        test    rcx, rcx
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rax]
        ret
```

The compiler managed to almost completely optimize away the `Iterator` benchmark.

That's why [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.black_box.html) exists. It tells the compiler not to optimize away certain things.

Here is your code with proper `black_box`es inserted at appropriate places:

```rust
use std::hint::black_box;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

const N_ITEMS: usize = 100000;
const N_BENCH_TIMES: i32 = 100;

pub fn bench_simple() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = black_box(vec![5; N_ITEMS]);
    for i in a.iter_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
    black_box(a);
}

pub fn bench_iterator() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = black_box(vec![5; N_ITEMS]);
    let a: Vec<i32> = a.iter_mut().map(|x| *x + 1).collect();
    black_box(a);
}

pub fn bench_foreach() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = black_box(vec![5; N_ITEMS]);
    a.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 1);
    black_box(a);
}

fn benchmark(name: &str, f: &dyn Fn()) {
    println!("Benchmark: {}", name);
    let mut time = Duration::new(0, 0);
    for _ in 0..N_BENCH_TIMES {
        let start_time = Instant::now();
        f();
        time += start_time.elapsed();
    }
    println!("Total: {:?} over {} instances", time, N_BENCH_TIMES);
    println!("Average: {:?}", time.div_f64(N_BENCH_TIMES as f64));
}

fn main() {
    benchmark("Simple", &bench_simple);
    benchmark("Iterator", &bench_iterator);
    benchmark("ForEach", &bench_foreach);
}
```

So what's the output now? Here are a couple of runs on my laptop:

```
Benchmark: Simple
Total: 13.9338ms over 100 instances
Average: 139.338µs
Benchmark: Iterator
Total: 4.9353ms over 100 instances
Average: 49.353µs
Benchmark: ForEach
Total: 7.554ms over 100 instances
Average: 75.54µs
```

```
Benchmark: Simple
Total: 6.1412ms over 100 instances
Average: 61.412µs
Benchmark: Iterator
Total: 12.5715ms over 100 instances
Average: 125.715µs
Benchmark: ForEach
Total: 14.4137ms over 100 instances
Average: 144.137µs
```

As you can see, the variations are **huge**.

To mitigate that, we need to use a proper benchmark crate like [`criterion`](https://docs.rs/criterion), which does things like warm-up and dynamic repetition count.

Here is your code rewritten with `criterion` in mind:

Note that this does not go into `main.rs`, but into a source file in the `benches/` directory. For more info, read the [criterion user guide](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/index.html).

```rust
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use std::hint::black_box;

const N_ITEMS: usize = 100000;

pub fn run_simple(mut a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in a.iter_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
    a
}

pub fn run_iterator(mut a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.iter_mut().map(|x| *x + 1).collect()
}

pub fn run_foreach(mut a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 1);
    a
}

fn do_bench(c: &mut Criterion, name: &str, f: impl Fn(Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>) {
    let mut a = Some(vec![5; N_ITEMS]);
    c.bench_function(name, |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            let data = black_box(a.take().unwrap());
            let data = f(data);
            a = Some(black_box(data));
        })
    });
}

fn bench_simple(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Simple", run_simple);
}
fn bench_iterator(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Iterator", run_iterator);
}
fn bench_foreach(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Foreach", run_foreach);
}

criterion_group!(benches, bench_simple, bench_iterator, bench_foreach);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
Simple                  time:   [23.375 µs 23.508 µs 23.657 µs]
Iterator                time:   [48.229 µs 48.762 µs 49.368 µs]
Foreach                 time:   [23.271 µs 23.384 µs 23.528 µs]
```

Note that `Simple` and `Foreach` are pretty much identical, while `Iterator` seems to be slower. Why is this?

The reason is that your implementation of `Iterator` uses `iter_mut`, which keeps the original vector alive. This isn't necessary in any way, however, so we can use `into_iter` instead, like so:

```rust
pub fn run_iterator(a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.into_iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect()
}
```

Re-running the benchmark with the new version yields:

```rust
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use std::hint::black_box;

const N_ITEMS: usize = 100000;

pub fn run_simple(mut a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for i in a.iter_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
    a
}

pub fn run_iterator(a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.into_iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect()
}

pub fn run_foreach(mut a: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x += 1);
    a
}

fn do_bench(c: &mut Criterion, name: &str, f: impl Fn(Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>) {
    let mut a = Some(vec![5; N_ITEMS]);
    c.bench_function(name, |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            let data = black_box(a.take().unwrap());
            let data = f(data);
            a = Some(black_box(data));
        })
    });
}

fn bench_simple(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Simple", run_simple);
}
fn bench_iterator(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Iterator", run_iterator);
}
fn bench_foreach(c: &mut Criterion) {
    do_bench(c, "Foreach", run_foreach);
}

criterion_group!(benches, bench_simple, bench_iterator, bench_foreach);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
Simple                  time:   [23.561 µs 24.038 µs 24.657 µs]
                        change: [-0.7221% +3.2799% +7.4864%] (p = 0.11 > 0.05)
                        No change in performance detected.

Iterator                time:   [23.180 µs 23.244 µs 23.318 µs]
                        change: [-52.691% -49.895% -46.210%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has improved.

Foreach                 time:   [23.217 µs 23.351 µs 23.515 µs]
                        change: [-3.0721% -0.0025% +3.1169%] (p = 1.00 > 0.05)
                        No change in performance detected.
```

And now you can see all three are identical. This is expected, because Rust iterators (if used properly) are zero-cost abstractions.

And yes, even the `.collect()` based one is identical - the Rust compiler can figure out that the old vector got destroyed and a new one of identical size gets allocated, and optimize that accordingly.

The [resulting assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/coovr4b3r) shows that `Simple` and `Foreach` compile to almost the exact same code. The `Iterator` one does in fact compile to different code; it still seems to perform the same, though.

This is because while the `Iterator` version has a little more setup/teardown code, the actual work-horse code is still identical:

```
# x86-64 with SSE2
        xor     edx, edx             # EDX = 0
        pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0           # set1_epi32(-1), cheaper than loading a vector of ones
.LBB1_9:                             # do{
        movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rbx + 4*rdx]        # load src[rdx+0..3] with a scaled-index addressing mode
        movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rbx + 4*rdx + 16]   # load dst[rdx+4..7]
        psubd   xmm1, xmm0                       # packed subtract of dword (32-bit) elements
        psubd   xmm2, xmm0
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rax + 4*rdx], xmm1   # store to a separate destination (RAX)
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rax + 4*rdx + 16], xmm2
        add     rdx, 8
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        jne     .LBB1_9              # }while(end != idx)
```

---

**Additional remark:**

If your code is **really** performance critical, consider adding `target-cpu=native` to your compilation flags. This makes your code no longer portable, but will make use of additional CPU features on your specific CPU.

With it enabled, I get:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS='-C target-cpu=native' cargo bench
Simple                  time:   [20.676 µs 20.762 µs 20.856 µs]
Iterator                time:   [20.660 µs 20.725 µs 20.798 µs]
Foreach                 time:   [20.638 µs 20.711 µs 20.786 µs]
```

It's not hugely faster, but it does make a difference.

If data fit in L2 or especially L1d cache, it would run about twice as fast on typical CPUs where 256-bit vector instructions (AVX2 for 256-bit integer) are available and have about the same cost as 128-bit vectors, but get twice as much work done per instruction.  So Haswell and later Intel, Zen 2 for AMD.  But not Alder Lake E-cores.

Comment: WRT `target-cpu`, you can get more performance at a lower compatibility cost by targeting specific features if you know which ones are most useful, or by targeting µarch levels like x86-64-v2 or x86-64-v4. Here it looks like the improvements come from using AVX's packed integer operations, so that would be `x86-64-v3`.

Comment: Though interestingly the unrolling is also a lot more aggressive, not sure why: in the original version it performs additions on 4 integers at a time, 2 per iteration. Using v3, not only does it perform additions on 8 integers at a time, it does additions per iteration.

Comment: @PeterCordes Aaaah, thanks for the edit. I was wondering why the compiler did a subtraction instead of an addition. But I now realize that subtracting `-1` is identical to adding `1`, and it seems cheapter to set up `-1` than `1`. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly.  `pcmpeqd` does need to run on an ALU execution unit to produce the all-one-bits value (unlike p[xor-zeroing which can be eliminated in the front-end]([What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)) on modern Intel), but most CPUs do recognize it as not having a data dependency on the old value of the register (early Silvermont-family didn't).  So it's like a mov-immediate in terms of out-of-order exec.